# Turn off LED by turning signal high/floating

Tags: microcontroller

I want to turn on/off the following lights using an LPC810:
[image: 3-led bike lights]
These lights are powered using two AAA batteries. This would provide 3 volts. I do not have the lights yet, so I cannot measure the current draw. However, as the LPC810 only allows for a couple of milliamps on it's digital output, I think it would not be clever to push the current through the chip.

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC81XM.pdf

To solve this I'm thinking of hooking the lights up as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Rsog.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This should turn on the lights when P1 and P2 go low, and turn them off when they go high.

Will this work? Will this be efficient, or will this result in quite a high current draw while the lights are off?

Am I reading the documentation correctly in that only 4 mA (I-oh) can be pulled from the pins, or can I simply hook up the positive side of the lights to P1 and P2?

Comment: A standard approach is to use a suitably rated transistor to switch the lights supply on and off; is there a particular reason why you've ruled that out?

Comment: Yes. The reason is: I'm a noob that usually only has to deal with digital signals and hadn't even thought of them... I'm gonna see if I can find the right ones, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: No problem, an n-channel MOSFET is probably suitable here as the easiest option. I'll have to look around to find a post that discusses how to select it based on its parameters but with such loads you might be able to get away with a "logic-level MOSFET" that can handle enough current (they almost always handle way more than 4 mA when used as a switch, depending on the size of the package perhaps as much as 4 or even 40 A)

Comment: Take a look at this https://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/using-mosfets-with-ttl-levels/ It will let you drive a lamp from a 3-volt processor. However, don't expect a very long operating life if you're working from AAA batteries. Also, you'll need to pretty much restrict yourself to red LEDs. White LEDs typically take more than 3 volts to light up brightly.

Comment: yes, a GPIO can typically sink more current than it can source, but not a whole lot more; use a transistor as a switch.

Comment: These bicycle lights are usually controlled by a small on-board cicruit that switches between Off - On - Flash. You will first have to make sure you can directly control the LEDs by disabling or altering the the built-in control circuitry.

Comment: @StarCat thanks for the heads up, but yeah, already did that.

Comment: @dandavis wait... "Sinking current" is a thing? Isn't it simply 0 amps on the chip as all the amps are "used up" by the lights? (Assuming those have a resistance of e.g. 1000, and the chip of 1, chip should only have to sink like 1 milli amp per amp the lights draw?)

Comment: amps are identical for the sink/source, the led, a resistor, etc; all series circuits.